# Generate numeric field automatically based on another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-order-by, sql-view

I have a table in SQL server with two columns, Name and Order. Name is a `varchar` column which contains student names, Order is an `int` column which contains the number in ascending order corresponding to the Name column in alphabetical order.

For example, the expected result should be like below

```
Names - Order

ABC - 2
AAA - 1
CCC - 3
XZZ - 5
XYZ - 4
```

Is there any option to generate the order column automatically whenever a new name gets inserted into the table?

Comment: Tables have _column_, not fields.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: I am using SQL DB

Comment: Which one? There are dozens of them. (Or do perhaps mean MS SQL Server?)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Database 2014

Comment: Look into using sequences.

Comment: Why do you need an order column? SQL Server will allow you to order alphabetically by the name column? And if you want a row number, us the row_number function. You don't need to store anything.

Answer (score 2):

> Order is an int column which contains the number in ascending order corresponding to the Name column in alphabetical order.

Just use `row_number()`. You should not be storing this derived information - instead, you can use a view:

```
create view myview as
select t.*, row_number() over(order by name) as rn
from mytable t
```

Note: `order` is a language keyword (as in `order by ...`), hence not a good choice for a column name; I used `rn` instead.